# Add a non-package folder containing classes into jar file structure

Tags: java, jar, directory, manifest

I'm trying to create by hand a .jar file containing my classes but my Manifest file doesn't find them.

The problem is my folder structure :

```
app   (root folder)
 |`-- bin/   (Is a simple folder)
 |     `-- client/   (Is a package)
 |            `-- *.class   (All classes)
 |     `-- (Others packages)
 |`-- MANIFEST.MF
 |`-- libs/
       `-- lib.jar
```

**Because my jar contains the bin/ folder, it doesn't find the classes.** When I create the jar without the bin/ folder, it works well, but I have to move my package structure outside this directory.

## Question

How can I make my jar **find my classes through my bin/ directory**, even if it is not a package ?

OR

How can I create my jar **passing through the bin/ directory**, adding all the client package without having to moving the package outside the bin/ ?

---

#### MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: libs/lib.jar
Main-Class: client.MainClient
```

(It has the needed empty line at the end)

#### Commands used

I use this commands to create my jar

```
jar -cvfm app.jar MANIFEST.MF bin/client/*.class
java -jar app.jar
Error : could not find or load main class client.MainClient
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't think you can arbitrarily modify the internal classpath of a jar like that.

Comment: `bin` must be the source directory for packing so it packs to `/client` (no feasible other solution). I would go for a build infrastructure like `maven` which gives best practices in the form of a directory structure and manages library dependencies.

Comment: That's what I though... Just wanted to know if it is possible !